# Joomla modal window "sbox" popup shifts background to the right

Tags: joomla, mootools, modal-dialog

I have noticed for a while that Joomla´s build in modal popup "sbox" moves the background (the entire body of the site) ca. 10 pixels to the right when I open a popup window. When I close the popup window the page is shifted back 10 pixels to the left.

You can see the problem on this page: 
http://www.traelastogbyggemarked.dk/vaerktoj/arbejdsbeklaedning/traesko/euro-dan-pu-finer-toffel-sort-detaljer

Just click on the product image and you can see the background moving.

I have noticed this on other sites aswell, for instance on this page page:
http://demo.joomlaxtc.com/free/index.php/modal-box-plugin

click on the demo link "Click Here"

The problem appears to be present in all browsers. As far as I know the sbox modal popup is a part of Joomla´s build-in mootools core. My site is running Joomla 2.5

Does anyone know how I can change this behavior and stop the modal popup from moving the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the modal.css and look for this:

```
/* Hides scrollbars */
.body-overlayed {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Try without it.

Comment: Perfect, removing that CSS solved the problem, thanks!
I don´t know how I managed to not notice the added body class "body-overlayed" when the popup is open.

Answer (score 0):

This should resolve the apparent shift:

```css
  /* Hides scrollbars */
   .body-overlayed {
       overflow: hidden;
       width: calc(100% - 16px);}
```

It subtracts the width of the scrollbar from the element when the class is applied.